# One liner to create QLabel with QPixmap

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

To create QLabel with QPixmap I'm currently using

```
label = QLabel()
label.setPixmap(QPixmap("path-to-img"))
```

So it's 2 lines.But I want one liner code.

I think following code could be an answer.

```
label = QLabel("<img src=path-toimg></img>")
```

But I suspect there is more elegant way.

Comment: What's wrong with the first code?

Comment: @cdonts: No problem except it is 2 lines.

Comment: The `QLabel` constructor doesn't take a `pixmap` argument, so probably there's no other way. You can still make a single line `label = QLabel(); label.setPixmap(QPixmap("path-to-img"))`. Why would you want one liner code?

Comment: Write a helper function taking a QPixmap, returning a QLabel?

Comment: The img tag one-liner works, so why don't you use that? By definition, there is no elegant way to play code-golf, which is all your question amounts to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after doing some research you can do it but it is considered non-pythonic since we abuse the `tuple` (you can do this with `list`, `dict` or any other object that can store multiple values and you are able to access these in a decent manner). The following code exploits the evaluation order of a tuple. It also makes it possible not only to create a label and assign a `QPixmap` to it but also to add it to a layout. As promised **all in a single line**. :D

```
layout.addWidget((lambda img, lbl: ((lambda i,l: l.setPixmap(i))(img,lbl), (lambda l: l)(lbl)))(QPixmap('../Pictures/IMAGE.jpg'), QLabel('Lambda'))[1])
```

The problem with `lambda` in Python is that it doesn't allow more than one expression in its body. And expression is also a keyword here - you cannot use statements! What we can do is however use a chain of lambdas. The code above works because of the fact that a lambda always returns a value.

**Example and explanation why this works:**

```
>>> x = lambda x,y: (x**y, x+y)
```

returns a tuple. Each element inside the tuple is evaluated so that the final tuple can be returned by the lambda expression. Here is an example how it works

```
>>> x(2,3)
(8,5)
```

The first tuple element `8` is created by evaluating `x**y`. The second one - the `5` - is the result of `x+y`.

Further we use the fact that we can reference the elements of a tuple and return what's stored at position X. If we take the numeric example from above we get

```
>>> x(2,3)[0]
8
>>> x(2,3)[1]
5
```

And this is exactly what we are doing here.

- **Outer lambda** `(lambda img, lbl: ...)(QPixmap('../Pictures/IMAGE.jpg'), QLabel('Lambda'))[1]` - this lambda receives a newly created `QPixmap` along  with a newly created`QLabel`. Since the outer lambda returns a tuple (see below) we can access the second element (see **second inner lambda**)
- **First inner lambda** `(lambda i,l: l.setPixmap(i))(img,lbl)` - we redirect the pixmap and label objects to it (both are passed as references) and call the `QLabel.setPixmap(...)` method
- **Second inner lambda** `(lambda l: l)(lbl)` - this is basically just redirecting the `QLabel` object  (which has been passed as argument to the outer lambda and setup by the first inner lambda) so that - after accessing the `[1]` element of our returned tuple we actually get an object that we can use.

If you want to store the created label you can omit the `layout.addWidget(...)` and simply assign the `lambda`'s result to a variable for further use. If you use `[0]` as index you will get a `None` since the **first inner lambda** returns `None`.

**AGAIN - WARNING!** This is - as mentioned above - abusing the way Python works. As suggested in the comment section you should use a normal `def` (named function) with a `return` statement.

Comment: Hmm, very complicated... But I understand what you mean. You used `lambda` like lisp's `(prongn ...)`. Very tricky, but it's no doubt, one liner.

Comment: Tricky, dirty and not pythonic. However there is no other way as far as I know to do all that in a single line without an extra `def` function, which adds more lines. :D Btw the non-pythonic part here is the fact that - as I've mentioned - unlike `Lisp` or `Haskell` Python's support for functional programming sucks. Don't ask me why but the author of the language doesn't want to add multi-expression support. In fact there was even a time when he wanted to abandon the whole `lambda` for Python 3 (lambdas are available in Python 2.7 too; not sure about earlier versions).